# Сould not open JPA EntityManager for transaction when using multiple transaction managers

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

> Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@20f78dcb] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] bound to thread

At first, I used a transaction manager that was created for use with the JDBC template.

```java
  @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager dbTxManager() {
        return new DataSourceTransactionManager(clientDestinationDataSource());
    }
```

However, in this case, it was impossible to save to the database (on the contrary, reading works without errors):

> threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'transactionManager' available: No matching TransactionManager bean found for qualifier 'transactionManager' - neither qualifier match nor bean name match!

Explicitly specifying the right manager in the Transactional annotation did not solve the problem.

```java
ClientRepositry repo;

@Transactional("dbTxManager")
    @Override
    public Long processClient(Client client){
    repo.findById(client.getId())

   ...

   repo.save(client); //error

}
```

I decided to set up a separate EntityManager.

```java
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "clientEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManagerSimple",
        basePackages = "com.integration")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
public class DbConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public HikariDataSource clientDataSource(DataSourceProperties clientDestinationDbProps) {
        return clientDestinationDbProps
                .initializeDataSourceBuilder()
                .type(HikariDataSource.class)
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean clientEntityManagerFactory(HikariDataSource clientDataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(clientDataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(
                "com.integration.domain",
                "com.integration.repository"
        );

        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManagerSimple(EntityManagerFactory clientEntityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(clientEntityManagerFactory);
    }
}
```

basePackages = "com.integration" - The root from where you need to scan your directories to find all the components for the current data source for which you are configuring EntityManager

At the time of data processing, it is not possible to open a transaction.

> threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Already value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@20f78dcb] for key [HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1)] bound to thread

Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Why are you using multiple transaction managers in the first place? If you are sharing the datasource with JDBC and JPA (so if it is the same) you can just use the `JpaTransactionManager` for both. Trying to use a `DataSourceTransactionManager` for JPA will not work hence the error.

Comment: I did notice that it happened, but I didn't realize that it was an error: an exception was thrown; the nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.Exception NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: A component named "TransactionManager" is unavailable: The corresponding TransactionManager component for the "TransactionManager" qualifier was not found - neither the qualifier nor the component name match!

Comment: At first, he did so. But even explicitly specifying an explicit transaction manager did not solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say with the comments. But as stated if you only use 1 datasource you only need 1 transaction manager not multiple. You only need multiple if you are using multiple datasourcs.

Comment: Exactly. There are several data sources, each with a transaction manager. In addition, there is another transaction manager for Artemis, another for Ibm mq.

Comment: in addition, I used DataSourceTransactionManager as an implementation, but it will not work, since in my case I additionally use spring-data-jpa (I checked it out).

Comment: Since I'm using spring-data-jpa, that's why I need the JpaTransactionManager.

Comment: Please read.. You only need multiple transaction managers if you have multiple datasources. You should **NOT** define multiple transaction managers for 1 datasource as that will lead to issues.

Comment: Like I said, I don't have a choice. you need to refine the existing code, but this does not work using the Transactional manager that is defined. What problems can this cause? I don't understand.

Comment: I give up. You clearly don't understand when to u se multiple transactionmanagers and when not. You are using the wrong transaction manager for the technology in use and that will simply never work.

Comment: The JpaTransactionManager is designed to manage transactions at the JPA level, and the JDBC template is designed to work with the database at the JDBC level. The two components use different mechanisms to manage transactions and are not interchangeable. If you are using JDBC template to access the database, than need use DataSourceTransactionManager to manage transactions

Comment: As mentioned numerous times before if you have 1 datasource using for both JDBC and JPA use the `JpaTransactionManager` as that is also capable for JDBC transactions. Use **1 transactionmanger per datasource**.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the error related to this topic, it was necessary to explicitly specify the transaction manager that produced it.

```java
  @Transactional(value = "transactionManagerSimple")
    @Override
    public Long processClient(Client client) {

...
```